# Show tooltip on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/G38nx/

So I have this table. I want to show a tooltip while rolling over certain td. For example pointing at cell with value 27 should show a tooltip "160cm:70kg".

Any easy way to do it?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th><th>50kg</th><th>55kg</th><th>60kg</th><th>65kg</th><th>70kg</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>160cm</th><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td><td>27</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>165cm</th><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td><td>26</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>170cm</th><td>17</td><td>19</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>175cm</th><td>16</td><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

td, th, .ff-fix {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

td:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
tr:hover{
  background-color: #ffa;  
}
}
```

JS:

```
function firefoxFix() {

    if ( /firefox/.test( window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) ) {

        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );

        for( var index = 0; index < tds.length; index++ ) {
            tds[index].innerHTML = '<div class="ff-fix">' + tds[index].innerHTML + '</div>';                     
        };

        var style = '<style>'
            + 'td { padding: 0 !important; }' 
            + 'td:hover::before, td:hover::after { background-color: transparent !important; }'
            + '</style>';
        document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', style );

    };

};

firefoxFix();
```

Comment: `<td title="info goes here">`

Comment: A tooltip as in jQueryUI, or a simple title tooltip?

Comment: I want to be able to style it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you might create the titles. It's fairly easy from that point to apply jQueryUI Tooltips, which allow custom styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/G38nx/25

```
$('td').each(function () {
    var myIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    var myTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('th').text();
    myTitle += ":";
    myTitle += $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + myIndex + ')').text(); 

    $(this).attr('title', myTitle);

    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Update: Per your comment, here's an example with image content and instant (no transition) show and hide:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/G38nx/31

```
$(this).tooltip({
    content: "<img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' />",
    show: false,
    hide: false
});
```

You'd have to use a data attribute to specify images for each cell, something like:

```
<th data-image-src="<img src='/images/myImage.jpg' />">...</th>
```

... and then:

```
$(this).tooltip({
    content: $(this).attr('data-img-src'),
    show: false,
    hide: false
});
```

Comment: Updated again to restore the Firefox fix function.

Comment: This is great! How can I make the tooltip show instantly? Without this fade effect?. Is it possible to specify image for each <th> and display it in tooltip?

Answer (score 2):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/dPe5n/)

**html**

```
<div id="uguu"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("td").hover(function (e) {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $("#uguu")
        .css("top", $(this).offset().top)
        .css("left", $(this).offset().left+40)
        .html($(this).siblings("th").text()+":"+$("table tr").first().find("th").eq(idx).text())
        .show();
}, function () {
    $("#uguu").hide();
});
```

**css**

```
#uguu {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#cef;
    z-index:400;
    border:1px solid ecf;
}
```